# Altdrag like to resize with mouse left in KDE

Tags: kde, window-manager, window-management

Altdrag is efficient. But I want to use mouse left button with other key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to resize
Because it's pretty difficult to resize by altdrag with mouse right on a laptop trackpad.
It's very easy to do this in some wms. Is it possible with KDE?

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed in the system settings, but only supports <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>/<kbd>Windows</kbd> keys. The mouse buttons can be freely assigned to different actions.

KDE > System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > [Tab] Windows Actions > [Section] Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame > [Droplist] Modifier Key

See also this bug report, where the default modifier key will be changed to <kbd>Meta</kbd> in the next kwin release:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399375

Comment: Thx. But tha't not enough. If possible, there should be two modifier keys for me to do the stuff.